# how do I get sha key for any repository' file

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I want to access sha key for any repository' files individually.

[image]

As you can see. There are a file structure and that is include a .git directory which I created with gitpython. I can get repository sha key for represent all files as follow;

```
from git import Repo

repo = Repo("graph/features")
master = repo.head.reference
print(master.commit.hexsha)
```

My question is that I want to generate sha key for any file such as file2.txt. Are there any method to realize that. I am sorry, I am new about using gitPython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read files then

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> file_text = 'content'
>>> hashlib.sha256(file_text.encode()).hexdigest()
'ed7002b439e9ac845f22357d822bac1444730fbdb6016d3ec9432297b9ec9f73'
>>>
```

Comment: In fact this approach is not what I want, but I will use it. thank you very much for your interest

Answer (score 0):

```
repo = Repo.init(path).git
index = Repo(path).index

# add file to repo
repo.add(filename)
index.commit(message)
```

path: repository (.git) path

filename : which file do you want to add

message : commit message

---

after that use method as fallow;

```
repo = Repo(path)
commit = repo.head.commit

sha = commit.hexsha
```